# Where do you modify TablixMember properties in the GUI in Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder

I am using Report Builder 2016 designing a report with multiple Tablixes.

When I attempt to preview my report withing report builder I am getting the following error:

> The TablixMember must have the same value set for the RepeatOnNewPage property as those following or preceding the dynamic TablixMember. (Expected Value: "True"; Actual Value: "False")

When I look at the raw XML of the .rdl file I can easily track down where the issue is coming from.

The offending node is the `<RepeatOnNewPage>true</RepeatOnNewPage>` from the snippet below, if I remove that node, it works fine. Based on the error, I also assume adding that node to the other TablixMember nodes should also work.

```
                <TablixRowHierarchy>
                  <TablixMembers>
                    <TablixMember>
                      <KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup>
                      <RepeatOnNewPage>true</RepeatOnNewPage>
                    </TablixMember>
                    <TablixMember>
                      <KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup>
                    </TablixMember>
                    <TablixMember>
                      <Group Name="Details2" />
                      <Visibility>
                        <Hidden>=iif(Fields!PrintFlag.Value="Y",false,true)</Hidden>
                      </Visibility>
                    </TablixMember>
                  </TablixMembers>
                </TablixRowHierarchy>
```

My question is, where did this get set in the actual GUI of Report Builder? I don't have the best understanding of TablixMembers but my tablix has 3 rows (the third row being the one with the Grouping) so I have to assume the three child nodes within the TablixMembers are the actual rows, meaning this property exists on my first row somewhere.

I've scoured the properties pane of the rows and can't figure out where this property is being set. Any help for my own understanding is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is actually hidden in the static row group properties.

Click the drop-down to the right of the "Column Groups" panel and select "Advanced"

[image]

Select the relevant static row group

[image]

and then you should be able to see these properties...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Alan Schofield for providing the answer. I also found an article that explain it before I noticed there was a response here.

Here is the source that describes the same thing:
https://www.ptr.co.uk/blog/ssrs-repeat-page-headers-every-page